# jQuery how to add class to specific div's

Tags: jquery, html, filter, each, addclass

Is there a way to add a class through jquery to all divs containing ul's with only one list element (like div.filter_7). With jQuery i need to go through every div.list-container and count the list elements. If the list elements are lower than 2 then jquery should append a class.

```
<div class="filter_group">
<div class="filter-holder filter_1">
<h4>Test</h4>
<div class="list-container">
    <ul class="list filter">
        <li class="list_id1">list_id1</li>
        <li class="list_id2">list_id2</li>
        <li class="list_id3">list_id3</li>
        <li class="list_id4">list_id4</li>
        <li class="list_id5">list_id5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="filter-holder filter_2">
<h4>Test</h4>
<div class="list-container">
    <ul class="list filter">
        <li class="list_id11">list_id11</li>
        <li class="list_id22">list_id22</li>
        <li class="list_id33">list_id33</li>
        <li class="list_id44">list_id44</li>
        <li class="list_id55">list_id55</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="filter-holder filter_6">
<h4>Test</h4>
<div class="list-container">
    <ul class="list filter">
        <li class="list_id111">list_id111</li>
        <li class="list_id222">list_id222</li>
        <li class="list_id555">list_id555</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="filter-holder filter_7">
<h4>Test</h4>
<div class="list-container">
    <ul class="list filter">
        <li class="list_id1111">list_id1111</li>
        <li class="list_id2221">list_id2222</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

​

Here is what i've done so far with jquery, but it seems wrong:

```
    var total = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.list-container').each(function(idx, item){
      total = $(".list-container>ul").size();
          if (6 >= total) {
           $('.list-container').parent('div').addClass('noshow');
    } else {
    alert(total);
    }              
    });
});
```

​

Comment: Can we safely assume that each `<div>` will only ever contain one `<ul>`, or do we need to account for, say, a `<div>` that has one `<ul>` with only one element and a second `<ul>` that has multiple elements (and, if we do, should this be hidden or not?).

Comment: Wait... is it "lower than two" or "only one" list item. Does an empty list get the noshow class too?  Your code doesn't exactly match your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You don't need to filter or each...**

You can use [jQuery.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/) in conjunction with `:only-child`.  As can be seen in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WAS3R/) demo and code below.

```
jQuery("div.list-container").has("li:only-child").addClass("noshow");
```

It's *WAY* cleaner to read than using filter.  You can modify the has a bit to make it more specific.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to work out exactly what you want as your text doesn't really match your html or example JS at all but try this:

```
$('div.filter-holder').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('li').length == 1;
}).addClass('noshow');
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/hyCaJ/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.filter-holder').filter(function(){
  return $('div.list-container li',this).length <= 2;
}).addClass('noshow');
```

You can use `.filter()` to apply more advanced logic to a result set (returning true keeps the element in the set, while returning false removes it from the set.

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/pMvHu/1/

Comment: Just caught you were trying to apply the class to the parent div (`.filter-holder`), not the list container (`.list-container`). Code updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try below script,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/gda6g/3/)

```
$('.filter-holder').filter (function () {
   return ($(this).find('ul li').length == 1) //Edit: changed to ==
}).addClass('noshow');
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `'.length` instead:

```
$('.list-container').each(function(){
  if ($('li', this).length <= 2) {
    $(this).parent().addClass('noshow');
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/we8Jj/

Comment: jquery size() and length are the same :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.list-container').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('ul').length >= 6) {
        $(this).addClass('noshow');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to count the `li`'s in every `ul`.

```
$('div.filter-holder ul').each(function() {
    if($(this).children().length == 1)
    {
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass('test')
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JHNja/)

Answer (score 0):

suppose "link_shopall" is div id, then to add class active

```
$('#link_shopall').classList.add('active')
```

To remove

```
$('#link_shopall').classList.remove('active')
```